# How can I duplicate a certain number using foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

code:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) {

echo $post['name'] 
};
?>
```

Result : 100 value 
I want to print 10 values only How that?

Comment: 100 values from database? If so, why you taking 100 result? Just limit to 10 result in query will fix your problem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
foreach($posts as $key => $post) {
  echo $post['name']; 

  //It will execute only ten times
  if($key == 9){
     break;
  }
}
```